# how to list users in linux?…local, remote, real and all users

Tags: linux, shell-script

how to list users in linux?…local, remote, real and all users

i have multiple Linux servers in same network i want to list all the users list in all the servers in single shot so any one have idea ..

and each users have different access privileges i want to take all the users details in single shot .

Comment: `getent passwd | awk " { print $1 }"`  for the rest, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269617/linux-equivalent-to-powershells-one-to-many-remoting/269626 ;  I advise focusing in one question at a time here in the future. Get also familiar with our FAQ, asking for tutorial is off-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list all user names and/or home directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409407/how-can-i-list-all-user-names-and-or-home-directories)

Answer (score 5):

This is done by simply running the `who` command (without any options). Consider the following example:

```
$ who
himanshu tty7         2012-08-07 05:33 (:0)
himanshu pts/0        2012-08-07 06:47 (:0.0)
himanshu pts/1        2012-08-07 07:58 (:0.0)
```

#### List all local users

You can list all the local users by doing a simple cat of the passwd (/etc/passwd) file.

`cat /etc/passwd`

#### List only real users

Let’s assume that the real users on the system have a home directory at /home.

`cat /etc/passwd | grep '/home' | cut -d: -f1`

#### List all users

If you need to get a list of all the users that have access to the system across many authentication services such as NIS, LDAP etc, then the command is `getent`.

You can use the `cut`, `grep` and `awk` commands to modify and format the output as described in the previous commands.

`getent passwd | cut -d: -f1`

Comment: I´m going to update the question for a more detailed solution

Comment: For listing real users, I had been thinking of listing all users with a UID greater than the `UID_MIN` as defined in `/etc/login.defs` but grepping for home is a good short-cut. Here's how it can be done with a single awk command: `awk -F : '/home/ {print $1 }' /etc/passwd`